npm строит неправильный путь, при попытки получения доступа к appdata npm папке
Простейший пример:
C:\Users\UserPC>npm install -g yarn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\UserPC\"C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm"
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\Users\UserPC\"C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm"'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Пробовал переустанавливать ноду, не помогает, в интернете решения найти не могу

¿Что выдает npm config list?

@user7860670 Спасибо, помогло решить проблему! Сейчас опубликую ответ

Спасибо @user7860670 за подсказку.
команда npm config list выводила следующее:
; "builtin" config from C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc

; prefix = "C:\\Users\\UserPC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm" ; overridden by user

; "user" config from C:\Users\UserPC\.npmrc

prefix = "C:\\Users\\UserPC\\\"C:\\Users\\UserPC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\""

; node bin location = D:\dev\programs\node.exe
; node version = v20.18.0
; npm local prefix = C:\Users\UserPC
; npm version = 9.8.1
; cwd = C:\Users\UserPC
; HOME = C:\Users\UserPC
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.

Для решения проблемы в файле C:\Users\UserPC\.npmrc поменял
prefix="C:\Users\UserPC\AppData\Roaming\npm"

на
prefix=AppData\Roaming\npm

